# Easy way to calculate integer powers of 2 in C#?

Tags: c#, integer

I'm sure this isn't as difficult as I'm making it out to be.

Would like to use something equivalent to `Math.Pow(double, double)` but outputting an integer.  I'm concerned about roundoff errors with the floating points.

The best I can come up with is:

```
uint myPower = 12;
uint myPowerOfTwo = (uint)Math.Pow(2.0, (double)myPower);
```

I thought of this:

```
uint myPowerOfTwo = 1 << myPower;    // doesn't work
```

but I get the error that operator "<<" cannot be used with operands of type int <strike>or</strike> and uint.

Any suggestions?  Thanks as always.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you will have to use a signed integer for the second operand  (right hand side) of the shift operator:

```
int myPower = 12;
int myPowerOfTwo = 1 << myPower;
```

Of course you can cast the result to another numeric type such as uint:

```
uint myPowerOfTwo = (uint) (1 << myPower);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/a1sway8w%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

> The left-shift operator (<<) shifts
>   its first operand left by the number
>   of bits specified by its second
>   operand. **The type of the second operand must be an int**.

Comment: OK, that seems to work!  But why the error message that operator "<<" cannot be used with operands of type int or uint?  Didn't I just use an int?

Comment: (for the OP) And cast to uint as a final step if necessary

Comment: @John are you sure it doesn't say *and*? meaning: the combination?

Comment: AHHHH!  Darn it I missed that!  It did say *and*.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you make an extension/static method, then it would be easier to find and correct any errors later and the optimizer would still inline it:

```
public static uint Exp2(this uint exponent) {
    return (uint)Math.Pow(2.0, (double)exponent);
}
```

Then you can use like:

```
uint myPowerOfTwo = myPower.Exp2();
```